# Creating Test Suite in Webdriver

Tags: java, testing, junit, webdriver

Apologies if this is  an obvious question.
I have written some tests in Java using webdriver backed selenium - these tests all run perfectly when ran individually. 
I would now like a way of running a selection of these together, in a testSuite.  From what I have found so far the suggestion has been the following:

```
package my.package;
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class My_TestSuite

public static Test suite() {
suite.addTestSuite(US298.class);
suite.addTestSuite(US111.class);
//etc
return suite;
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite());
}
}
```

I got this from attempting to export an existing test suite from the Selenium IDE, to try and give me an idea as to how to do this but it has not helped!
Any help greatly appreciated - many thanks.

Comment: What is the actual error that you're getting? Can you give an example of one of your tests? Are you using JUnit 3 or 4, that is are your test classes extending TestCase or are the methods annotated with @Test?

Comment: My test cases are annotated with @Test, and I'm using JUnit 4 - I'm getting an error on the "addTestSuite" bit - it says 'the method addTestSuite(Class<? extends TestCase>) in the type TestSuite is not applicable for the arguments (Class<US298>)' does that shed any more light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your comment about using JUnit 4, the problem is that you're actually using a JUnit 3 style test suite with JUnit 4 tests. You need to use the JUnit 4 [Suite](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Suite.html). This has the following format:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class })
public class AllTestsSuite {
}
```

The `junit.framework.*` classes are JUnit 3, and the `org.junit.*` classes are JUnit 4.

Comment: Hmmm. I have a similar problem - and i exported my suite from the IDE (v 2.9.1) using "Export test case as ... Java / JUnit 4 / WebDriver".   I added the RunWith and SuiteClasses, but then found (with the help of another question) that the test classes (which compiled and run OK on their own) must extend junit.framework.TestCase
Is the JUnit 4 export not really useable yet?

Answer (score 1):

I use TestNG Suites see the [doc](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)
at 3.textng.xml

It s easy to use

Example:

```
<test name="init">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.example.Setup" />
        <class name="com.example.Login"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="myTests">
    <packages>
        <package name="com.example.tests"/>
    </packages>
</test>
```

You would have to adjust your tests to testng of course, but thats easily done.
I also suggest that you use webdriver tests and not webdriver backed but thats just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

@tarken

When you use testNG what code do you write for executing and invoking test suite considering this as an example from above mentioned piece of code

```
package my.package;
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class My_TestSuite

public static Test suite() {
suite.addTestSuite(US298.class);
suite.addTestSuite(US111.class);
//etc
return suite;
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite());
}
}
```