# JUnit Test Suite for Selenium 2

Tags: selenium, junit4

I have converted a Selenium Test Suite into JUnit from Selenium IDE, and trying to execute from eclipse. But there is an error in my script in

```
suite.addTestSuite(Open_Google_IE.class);
suite.addTestSuite(Open_Google_FireFox.class);
```

Error message: The method addTestSuite(Class) in the type TestSuite is not applicable for the arguments (Class).

Please advise what could be the reason. I have also verified [Creating Test Suite in Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633800/creating-test-suite-in-webdriver) and updated test suite but still throws that error.

JUnit TestSuite

```
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses(value = {Open_Google_IE.class, Open_Google_FireFox.class})

public class OpenGoogle {

    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTestSuite(Open_Google_IE.class);
        suite.addTestSuite(Open_Google_FireFox.class);
        return suite;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the code is OK.

`addTestSuite()` can only take classes that extend `junit.framework.TestCase`. Please make sure your classes extend that one, or find another way around...

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Selenium / JUnit. Can you please let me know how to extend junit.framework.TestCase? Do you mean to import them?

import junit.framework.TestSuite;

Also if selenium test case is in JUnit WebDriverBacked then TestSuite work, but if test case is JUnit WebDriver then addTestSuite throws error. Please advise.

Comment: That means that in `Open_Google_IE.java` file, you need to state `public class Open_Google_IE extends TestCase` and also import it there. But all this is kinda against the JUnit philosophy, because it would do the most if this work for you... But I still think this would work :)

Comment: After included that, it is not throwing error in Test Suite (in addTestSuite(testClass) step). But test case (Open_Google_IE class) is failing to execute. However I have verified in <http://www.coderanch.com/t/96536/Testing/Trouble-addTestSuite-vs-addTest> and modified as addTest(new TestSuite(testClass)); then it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your class has to extend `SeleniumTestBase`

like this one :

```
public class CreateAccountTestCase extends SeleniumTestBase {
```