# How to set up Selenium 2.x Test Suites in the same Webdriver in Eclipse (JUnit4)

Tags: eclipse, selenium, junit4, test-suite

I have been sifting through the answers on stack for a while now and have come across some examples of work that seem to accomplish this or at least come close.

- [Use same web driver throughout selenium suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990683/use-same-web-driver-throughout-selenium-suite)
- [Before and After Suite execution hook in jUnit 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82949/before-and-after-suite-execution-hook-in-junit-4-x#177069)
- [JUnit Test Suite for Selenium 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896057/junit-test-suite-for-selenium-2)

All I want to be able to do is export selenium test cases as JUnit4 files, bring them into eclipse and modify them as needed, then be able to add or remove it from a test suite. When the test suite runs, it should open one webdriver window and run through each test case, just the same way it runs in the selenium IDE on the base firefox window. The only catch seems to be the webdriver class. I have tried referencing this between test case classes, which seems to keep the window up without throwing an error, but the second test case never runs, like it's stuck in a loop, or stopped at @Before

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({TestCase1.class,TestCase2.class})
public class RunTestSuite {

}
```

^^^ Test Suite example ^^^

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class TestCase1 {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.google.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testOpen() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "");
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

^^^ Test case 1 ^^^

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class TestCase2 {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    if (TestCase1.driver != null) {
      driver = TestCase1.driver;
  } else {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }
    baseUrl = "http://www.google.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testOpen() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "");
  }

@After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

^^^ Test Case 2 ^^^

Thanks for any help received!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the access modifier of the driver instance from private to static public so that it can be accessed by the second class.
Also make sure both classes at the same package.

Here is how it should be at TestCase1 class

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

I tried it and it works fine with me.