# Selenium webDriver test suite

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could anybody pass me any link that might help me creating a Selenium Test Suite with the connection of Selenium WebDriver

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633800/creating-test-suite-in-webdriver

Comment: Thx but I dun have script yet, I need follow guid lines of how to create it from scratch

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for SO as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.